# Redirect not obeying front page URL

Tags: redirection

We are using this module for our redirection for 404's and manually created redirects.
The site has a number of pages translated for the American audience. We added a redirect today for a page and simply pointed the redirect url to `<front>`. The referring URL is http://www.example.com/when-to-go/october. In the *General site* settings, the front page is set to /homepage. (A Basic page for this exists.)

Now when going to http://www.example.com/when-to-go/october, the users are redirected to http://www.example.com/en-us which gives a *The page isn't redirecting properly* error.

There are two issues:

- It should simply send users to /homepage, which is what is set to
- If we wanted the American version, then it should use *en-US* not *en-us*; Drupal seems to be treating this as case sensitive

Comment: Hopefully that's not your actual version? If so read https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2018-002 as soon as you can

Comment: Nope, production has been updated, this is on my local dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A circular redirect was been caused which stopped the redirect to front working. Checking the redirects already created and removing the offending ones fixed the issue.